Soft snapping HorizontalPager in Android Jetpack Compose
im trying to achieve a soft snapping for HorizontalPager in Android Jetpack Compose, here are my code:
HorizontalPager(
   state = pagerState,
   modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxSize(),
   beyondViewportPageCount = 1,
   flingBehavior = PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(
      state = pagerState,
      snapAnimationSpec = spring(
         stiffness = Spring.StiffnessVeryLow,
         visibilityThreshold = 3f
      ),
   ),
){
// pages
}

i set the fling behavior to slow stiffness and longer visibility threshold, it did make the horizontal pager snap slower and softer, but it only happened when i swipe the page slowly and release my finger slower, but when i swipe it fast, or i use:
pagerState.animateScrollToPage(
   page = currentPageIndex.intValue + 1,
   animationSpec = spring(
      stiffness = Spring.StiffnessVeryLow,
      visibilityThreshold = 3f
   )
)

it keep doing hard snapping, not soft snapping like i expected.
why and how to fix this?
p/s: this is the code i found from Pager API:
@Composable
    fun flingBehavior(
        state: PagerState,
        pagerSnapDistance: PagerSnapDistance = PagerSnapDistance.atMost(1),
        decayAnimationSpec: DecayAnimationSpec<Float> = rememberSplineBasedDecay(),
        snapAnimationSpec: AnimationSpec<Float> = spring(
            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow,
            visibilityThreshold = Int.VisibilityThreshold.toFloat()
        ),
        @FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0) snapPositionalThreshold: Float = 0.5f
    ): TargetedFlingBehavior {
        require(snapPositionalThreshold in 0f..1f) {
            "snapPositionalThreshold should be a number between 0 and 1. " +
                "You've specified $snapPositionalThreshold"
        }
        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
        return remember(
            state,
            decayAnimationSpec,
            snapAnimationSpec,
            pagerSnapDistance,
            density,
            layoutDirection
        ) {
            val snapLayoutInfoProvider =
                SnapLayoutInfoProvider(
                    state,
                    pagerSnapDistance
                ) { flingVelocity, lowerBound, upperBound ->
                    calculateFinalSnappingBound(
                        pagerState = state,
                        layoutDirection = layoutDirection,
                        snapPositionalThreshold = snapPositionalThreshold,
                        flingVelocity = flingVelocity,
                        lowerBoundOffset = lowerBound,
                        upperBoundOffset = upperBound
                    )
                }

            snapFlingBehavior(
                snapLayoutInfoProvider = snapLayoutInfoProvider,
                decayAnimationSpec = decayAnimationSpec,
                snapAnimationSpec = snapAnimationSpec
            )
        }
    }

they set:
snapAnimationSpec: AnimationSpec<Float> = spring(
            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow,
            visibilityThreshold = Int.VisibilityThreshold.toFloat()
        ),

for the snapping animation.
